# Inject scope value to angularJS function

Tags: angularjs, scope

DEMO: `http://jsbin.com/opUYApa/1/edit?html,js,output`

This is my first ever try at AngularJS.
Im trying to create a calculator. Calculator is done with CSS3.

When user submits the SUM amount, I want to store and display it Back on the page.
I tried to do this, but its not working at all.

Belwo image is just a HTML UI, The amount in the STEP 1 (**Rs. 40,000**) should update only when users hits the EQUAL TO Button (**SUM** =) and it should take that SUM from calculator to the TEXT inside STEP 1 and so on..
[image: Demo HTML image from actual project]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have `ng-controlller` instead `ng-controlller`

Further, you didn't define `ng-app`. It should be like:

```
<body ng-app='sipApp'>

  <div ng-controller="amountCtrl">
```

See fixed <kbd>[Demo](http://jsbin.com/UCaVaHeJ/1/edit)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for spotting the spelling mistake. Damm on me :(